# How do I get GHCi to show me an ambiguous type signature?

Tags: haskell, ghci, ambiguous-types

If I have an expression that I know has an ambiguous type, is there a way to get GHCi to actually tell me that type in full, so I can see the exact ambiguity for myself, instead of having to piece it together from bits of the error messages? Example:

```
GHCi, version 9.0.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> default ()
ghci> :t +v show . read

<interactive>:1:1: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘b0’ arising from a use of ‘show’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Show b0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 21 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘show’
      In the expression: show . read
      In the expression: show . read

<interactive>:1:8: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘b0’ arising from a use of ‘read’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Read b0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘b0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Read Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read a => Read (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        instance Read Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
        ...plus 23 others
        ...plus 10 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the second argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘read’
      In the expression: show . read
      In the expression: show . read
ghci>
```

In that example, what I want is for GHCi to tell me `show . read :: (Show a, Read a) => String -> String` or something like that.

Comment: Try after `:set -fdefer-type-errors`. This still prints the errors, but also shows the final type at the end.

Comment: @alias That gives me `show . read :: String -> String`, which is missing the part that I'm most interested in.

Comment: How about enabling `-XScopedTypeVariables`, importing `Data.Proxy` and modifying the expression to something like `\(Proxy :: Proxy a) -> show . id @a . read`.

Comment: @danidiaz That "works", but knowing the right place to put the `id @a` basically requires that you already know exactly what's going on with the ambiguity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GHCi is giving you the information you want, just not in the format you want.

With `-fdefer-type-errors` you get `show . read :: String -> String` after the errors. You're disappointed that it's not something like `show . read :: (Read a, Show a) => String -> String`.

The trouble is that the whole reason it is ambiguous is that the type variable `a` *doesn't* appear in the type of the overall expression, in order for the constraints to be attached. The constraints have to be solved "internally" to the expression, having nothing to do with the overall type `String -> String`.

GHC could of course add a spurious type variable to the type anyway, and say `show . read :: (Read a, Show a) => String -> String` just to tell you about the ambiguous type. But it *already* tells you about the ambiguous type, and if you actually read the error messages it tells you:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘show’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Show a0)’ from being solved.
```

Exactly what the problem is

```
  Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘a0’ should be.
```

That to fix it, you probably have to add more type information

```
  These potential instances exist:
    instance Show Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance Show Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    instance Show a => Show (Maybe a) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
    ...plus 22 others
    ...plus 21 instances involving out-of-scope type
```

A list of "potential" instances telling you what types you might be able to use in that additional type information it suggested you might need (this isn't very useful here, admittedly).

```
• In the first argument of ‘(.)’, namely ‘show’
  In the expression: show . read
```

Exactly *where* the problem is; pinpointing the exact sub-expression (because there could conceivably be more than one use of `show` on the same line).

`show` is the exact point in the code where a `Show` instance is needed and there is ambiguity about what type it should be using to find an instance. Not the return type of the call to `.`, which is unambiguously `String -> String`. So that's what GHC tells you (and similarly for the `Read` constraint in the next error message).

Consider this example:

```
ghci> :t length [1] + 10
length [1] + 10 :: Int
```

Under normal defaulting rules, that's fine. With `default ()` you get an ambiguous type error about being unable to solve the constraint `Num a0`. But is seeing the following type helpful?

```
length [1] + 10 :: (Num a) => Int
```

How do I know where the ambiguity is from that? Is it the `1` or the `10`, or does `length` maybe need a `Num` constraint (it could have been written like `genericLength`)? What GHC actually tells you is<sup>1</sup>:

```
• Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from the literal ‘1’
  prevents the constraint ‘(Num a0)’ from being solved
```

Which is **more** informative than what you want.

You say you want to "see the exact ambiguity for myself, instead of having to piece it together from bits of the error messages", but that's actually not what you're asking for. GHC **is** telling you the exact ambiguity (both the constraint that can't be solved and where it needs to be solved). What you are asking for is to see a type signature with variables in the constraints that don't appear on the right hand side of the `=>`, so that you can infer what must have gone wrong in the internals to cause that instead of reading the error message where it *tells* you what went wrong in the internals to cause that.

Presumably you want that because it would be much shorter and easier for you to recognise, which I can certainly understand! I think the right way to deal with that problem though is just to learn GHC's error messages until you can "pattern match" `Ambiguous type variable ‘a0’ arising from a use of ‘read’ prevents the constraint ‘(Read a0)’ from being solved.` just as easily as you can `(Read a, Show a) => String -> String`.

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact the return type of `length` is unambiguously `Int`, which sets the `Num` constraint used by `+` and `10` to `Int`, so the overall expression is unambiguously typed `Int`. The ambiguity is solely in the type of the `1` inside the list, not in the return type of `+`, so there should not be a `Num` constraint in the result.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get ghci to tell you this ambiguous type, but don't worry. This `show . read` example is rather artificial and you won't run into it in practice. You can at least make a definition out of it

```hs
readShow :: forall a. Read a => Show a => String -> String
readShow = show @a . read @a
```

Comment: Sure, `:t readShow` will give me the type I wanted to see now, but that just seems silly, since the only way it will accept the definition of `readShow` is if I give it the type! I suppose the point of your answer is to say "sorry, you can't do that", though.

Comment: You already have to know what's going on to get it printed, but I suppose it's possible: you can `:set -XTypeApplications -XScopedTypeVariables -XPartialTypeSignatures -Wno-partial-type-signatures` and then check the type in ghci `:type show @a . read :: forall a. _ => _`. This is like the `id @a` solution without a `Proxy` argument

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get GHCI to tell you. I think this is because even if you turn on, say, AllowAmbiguoustypes so that the expression compiles, GHCI's defaulting rules resolve the the readable type as `()`, rather than as a type parameter. There's no more interesting type left to show than `String -> String`. And there's no point leaving it polymorphic, because there's no place a client of this function could possibly put a type annotation to indicate what type they want to read as.

Contrast this with `read . show`, which GHCI will happily give you the type for because it can infer the type to use based on the arguments given.

Comment: I disabled type defaulting with `default ()` though.